# Can i do architecture for all project on push change detection?

Tags: angular

I going to start new big project on Angular 8.I set next line for all components

```
@Component({
...
changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
...
})
```

can I make such a project?  Or will I have to abandon the OnPush strategy in some cases for implement project

Comment: Yes its possible for you to do that

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use that but more importantly, I will suggest using where it is actually required otherwise you will fall in less error-prone code and performance issue.

So, **changeDetectionStrategy** provided by the angular core library. I am sharing a simple use-case I have used in a project, based on that you can relate and use it where it required.

Consider two-component on a page.

2. **Table component** (To display data 10K rows and 10 columns)
3. **Form Component** (Take user input and  have validation etc and submit button to add data in table)

Let suppose you already have 10K rows and 10 columns (10K*10) cells (td)

And user is filling the form angular validating forms with validators and running change detection cycle.

So the change detection cycle run form top to bottom in dom tree and it will run for all 
(10K*10) cells in tables and make it slow, you will notice performance issues with IE browser or in case more data with chrome as well.

So when a user interacting with form, we don't need to run change detection on table component, here you can use **onPush** strategy in the table component. That will increase performance significantly.

**Here is the Summary**

[(10K*10) + form controls ]object checks on each Change detection cycle while editing the form

after **onPush** strategy

[form controls] object checks on the each change detection cycle.

NOTE: In **onPush** strategy when use change input data of component by reference it will trigger the change detection strategy

```
onFormSubmit(){
  this.rows.push(this.formObject); // this will trigger change detection in table
}
<form-component></form-component>
<table-component [data]="rows"></table-component>
```